# Como sincronizar meu projeto com o GitHub

Tags: git, github

Olá eu tenho eu iniciei um projeto via github no Intellij. Clonei os dados do github. fiz o login via cmd e configurei tudo. porem quando dou commit. aparece que o commit foi realizado com sucesso. Mas no meu repositório do git nada muda. Eu acho que ele não esta alterando no mesmo repositório que eu desejo

Comment: falta `git push`

Comment: como configurar? existe algum tutorial?

Comment: ja consegui. vlw

Answer (score 1):

O GIT é um sistema de controle de versão que funciona com 4 áreas de trabalho, sendo 3 delas locais: *Working*, *Staging*, e *Local*. Quando você cria o projeto ele inicialmente está na área *Working*. Quando você modifica dados e adiciona os mesmos para preparar o commit, eles vão para a área *Staging*. Quando você termina o trabalho e commita, eles vão para a área *Local*, que é o seu repositório ainda local. Para que tudo seja enviado para a área *Remote*, você precisa usar o comando *git push*. É isso que falta para que você consiga visualizar as suas mudanças no GitHub. 
Para melhor entendimento do Git, eu recomendo esse [site](https://learngitbranching.js.org/) bem bacana com uma forma bem interativa de aprender.

Comment: E se alguém estiver contribuindo e você quer pegar as mudanças da outra pessoa, basta um `git pull`.